# Passing each element of a List through a function and then into another List

Tags: c#, list

I have a List of `TypeA`

```
List<A> ListA = new List<A> {
  new A("example1"), 
  new A("example2"), 
  new A("example3")
};
```

And I have to move each element of the list to a List of `TypeB` to do this i need to put each element through a function `convertAtoB(A a)` so this would work if the List of A and B are static and I could just copy and paste like so

```
List<B> ListB = new List<B> {
  convertAtoB(ListA[0]),
  convertAtoB(ListA[1]),
  convertAtoB(ListA[2]),
}
```

However these Lists are not static in size.

I tried using Foreach

```
List<B> ListB = List<A>.Foreach(delegate(A a){
       return convertAtoB(a);
});
```

However it seems Foreach does not return a List.

Comment: Use Linq’s Select and ToList

Comment: Lists are not static in size. They will increase their size automatically if needed as you add items.

Answer (score 3):

[LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/working-with-linq) has the tools for such basic collection transformations.

Use `Select` to perform a map, and the `ToList` to move results to a new collection:

```cs
List<B> listB = listA.Select(convertAtoB).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *convert* items of the list

> pass each element through a fuction

you can do it *straitforward* with a help of [ConvertAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.convertall?view=net-7.0):

```
List<B> ListB = ListA.ConvertAll(convertAToB);
```